# Why XOR have first letter X?

Tags: logical-operators

I began to disassemble the bit operations.And I have a simple question.I disassebled such operations as OR and XOR ,but something that is not understood.Why XOR have first letter X?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: From "eXclusive OR" - [EOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eeyore) might have elicited too many pooh jokes.

Comment: I just googled "xor" and it was right there.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to remember that way, since XOR sounds more like eXclusive OR.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 0):

XOR Truthtable for two variables is nothing but either ... or.

In English, the construct "either ... or" is usually used to indicate exclusive or and "or" generally used for inclusive. **So XOR is Exclusive OR**

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)